# Unable to print items from two arrays in intervals

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

So I have two arrays with the same number of items in each of them. I have been trying to print those items in intervals in the console. Something like this:

```
1
Bruce Wayne
45
```

Then after a one second interval it will print:

```
2
Clark Kent
43


and so on till the last item.
```

It will stop when all the items have been printed.

Right now I get something like this:

```
1
Clark Kent
43


3
undefined
```

So here is the code I tried:

```js
const superheroes = [
    {
        "name": "Bruce Wayne",
        "age": 45
    },
    {
        "name": "Clark Kent",
        "age": 43
    },
    {
        "name": "Oliver Queen",
        "age": 41
    },
    ,
    {
        "name": "Barry Allen",
        "age": 25
    }
];

const arr = [
    '1',
    '2',
    '3',
    '4'
];
const startBtn = document.querySelector('#start');
let index                       = 0;


$(startBtn).click(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            const arrItem       = arr[index++];
            const superheroItem = superheroes[index++];
            
            console.log(arrItem);
            console.log(superheroItem);

            if(index == arr.length){
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
        }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="start">Start</button>
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: There is an issue with how you're using the post increment operator. Check this to understand it's working
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Increment#postfix_increment

Comment: What needs to be fixed? What happens when you run it? BTW, when you increment your index with `index++` it increments AFTER you use that variable, so if you start at 0, arrItem will be arr[0] and superHeroItem will be superheroes[1]. Your next arrItem will be arr[2], superHeroItem will be superHeroes[3], and so on.

Comment: @AHMEDSAJJAD oh I understand. Any solution?

Comment: @user1599011 If you don't mind can you please read the post?. I have provided everything there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you need to increment your index after the code.
Try to re-write this code with some kind of loop on the superheroes collection.

```js
const superheroes = [
    {
        "name": "Bruce Wayne",
        "age": 45
    },
    {
        "name": "Clark Kent",
        "age": 43
    },
    {
        "name": "Oliver Queen",
        "age": 41
    },
    {
        "name": "Barry Allen",
        "age": 25
    }
];

const arr = [
    '1',
    '2',
    '3',
    '4'
];
const startBtn = document.querySelector('#start');
let index                       = 0;


$(startBtn).click(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            let arrItem       = arr[index];
            let superheroItem = superheroes[index];
            
            console.log(arrItem);
            console.log(superheroItem);

            if(index === arr.length - 1){
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
            
            index ++;
        }, 1000);
       
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="start">Start</button>
```

Comment: `if (++index === arr.length)`

Comment: @Oleksandr Mate, it's not working. The first item getting printed is 0 instead of 1 as the first item in ```arr``` is 1,

Comment: @zak, due to a typo. he had `const arr = ["0", "1", ...]`

Comment: @Zak it's fixed for a 1,2..etc.

Answer (score 1):

You are reusing the index variable and increment it multiple times. Because the array is zero indexed you don't want to increment the array before the first print. Then only increment it once each loop.

Also there is an extra comma in your superhero array.

```js
const superheroes = [
        {
            "name": "Bruce Wayne",
            "age": 45
        },
        {
            "name": "Clark Kent",
            "age": 43
        },
        {
            "name": "Oliver Queen",
            "age": 41
        },
        {
            "name": "Barry Allen",
            "age": 25
        }
    ];

const arr = [
  '1',
  '2',
  '3',
  '4'
];
const startBtn = document.querySelector('#start');
let index                       = 0;


$(startBtn).click(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    const arrItem       = arr[index];
    const superheroItem = superheroes[index];

    console.log("index: ",index);
    console.log(arrItem);
    console.log(superheroItem);

    index++

    if(index == arr.length){
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="start">Start</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to increment like this:

```
const arrItem       = arr[index++];
const superheroItem = superheroes[index++];
```

should be:

```
const arrItem = arr[index];
const superheroItem = superheroes[index];

index++;
```

since the corresponding data is at the same index in both arrays.

Also, I would recommend using a `for` loop to iterate over the array, instead of `setInterval` with a manual counter (it helps avoid bugs like these). If you really need a 1 second delay in between each iteration of the loop then a more modern way to approach it might be to await a timeout upon each iteration, something like this:

```js
const superheroes = [{
    "name": "Bruce Wayne",
    "age": 45
  },
  {
    "name": "Clark Kent",
    "age": 43
  },
  {
    "name": "Oliver Queen",
    "age": 41
  },
  {
    "name": "Barry Allen",
    "age": 25
  }
];

const arr = [
  '1',
  '2',
  '3',
  '4'
];

async function handleStartBtnClick(e) {
  //Remove the handler, so clicking the button multiple times does nothing
  e.target.removeEventListener('click', handleStartBtnClick);
  //Disable the button and give and informational message
  e.target.disabled = true;
  msgSpan.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<font color="red">Please wait until current rollcall completes..</font>');

  await doHeroRollcall();
  //Add the handler back now that we're ready to call it again
  e.target.addEventListener('click', handleStartBtnClick);
  //Enable the button and give and clear informational message
  e.target.disabled = false;
  msgSpan.innerHTML = "";
}

async function doHeroRollcall() {
  console.clear();

  for (let i = 0; i < superheroes.length; i++) {
    console.log(`name = ${superheroes[i].name}, age = ${superheroes[i].age} - ${arr[i]}`);
    await doTimeout();
  }
}

function doTimeout() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve();
    }, 1000);
  });
}

const startBtn = document.querySelector('#start');
const msgSpan = document.querySelector('#msg');

startBtn.addEventListener('click', handleStartBtnClick);
```

```html
<button id="start">Start</button>
<span id="msg"></span>
```

This way you dont have to worry about calling `clearInterval()` somewhere in your code.